# Eclipse Neon error on startup after being asked for workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

Just installed the newest Eclipse Neon for the first time on my PC. After being asked for the work space I get an error message asking me to check .log. This is the message. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
!SESSION 2017-09-26 14:29:06.537 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-26 14:29:11.308
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is due to using Java 9, can either download Java 8 JDK and point Eclipse to use it or follow this configuration.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

I would recommend just using a java 8 JDK as the java 9 support for is still beta.

Comment: How do I go about pointing Eclipse to use JDK 8? I can't open eclipse to do it.

Comment: see the answer marked at the top. It's configured through a configuration file - `eclipse.ini`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369792/why-wont-eclipse-oxygen-start-for-the-first-time