# Eclipse will not open on Mac Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Oxygen on my MacBook Pro the same as my MacBook Air. Eclipse runs on my air but I really need it to run on my Pro. Whenever I open Eclipse I create a new workspace and then it crashes and says to view the log. I have tried almost everything online and I have no idea what to do next.

Here is the log:

```
> !SESSION 2017-09-27 14:17:43.999 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rellew/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rellew/.eclipse_keyring

>!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-27 14:17:49.191
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 24 more

>!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-27 14:17:49.199
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 21 more
>!SESSION 2017-09-27 14:26:01.789 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rellew/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rellew/.eclipse_keyring

>!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-27 14:26:10.459
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 24 more

>!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-27 14:26:10.464
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 21 more
!SESSION 2017-09-27 14:29:42.475 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rellew/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rellew/.eclipse_keyring

>!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-27 14:29:46.226
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 24 more

>!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-27 14:29:46.230
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/2670892 Eclipse Oxygen will not run with Java 9 unless you modify the eclipse.ini or install the Java 9 support patch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you google the error? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493761

It looks like it was a bug in certain releases of Java Eclipse with Java 9.  Try re-downloading the latest versions of each and trying again.

Comment: Until Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) is released on 11th October there is no version of Eclipse that you can download that will run on Java 9 without modificiation.