# Mac OS X Eclipse IDE installation .metadata/.log error

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, metadata

I'm a new Mac user, and I've been trying to install Eclipse IDE Oxygen for Java Devs, but I get the "An error has occurred. See the log file [workspace path]/.metadata/.log" error. Its a fresh, first-time install, and I've tried using the tar.gz download and the installer. I've seen other answers say to delete the .metadata folder, but the workspace folder has nothing in it after this failed installation.

I've tried the newest Java version, the legacy Java 6 for Mac, both with no luck. I tried using older versions of Eclipse as well, to no end.

Every Mac user in my class has come across the same issue as me, so is it some incompatibility with Java/Eclipse versions and Mac OS? How can we get this working?

Comment: - Anything in the  `[workspace path]/.metadata/.log` file?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? For Java 9 you have to edit the `eclipse.ini` and add `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`

Comment: the workspace folder will show up after the error message shows, but its completely empty.

Comment: Have you checked if it is empty with `ls -a` from the command prompt?

Comment: There will be a `.log` file in the `.metadata` directory but files and directories starting with `.` are hidden and aren't shown by Finder. If you are using Java 9 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/2670892)

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Eclipse's known issues list:

> Configure Eclipse for Java 9 modules Since the Eclipse SDK uses types
>   that aren't in the java.base module, you need to add the following
>   vmargs to eclipse.ini:
>
> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
>
> Your project might fail to run because you use types that are neither in java.base or java.se.ee, e.g. types from
>   javafx.base. In that case you have to figure out which module(s) you
>   need to add with --add-modules.

So simply, add this line after -vmargs:

```
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Your eclipse.ini should look like that:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
<path_to_java>\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

For reference, check the known issues of Eclipse with JVM running on SDK 9.
Check them [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9#Configure_Eclipse_to_run_on_Java_9_VM)

Also the bug was reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493761)

Comment: Where is the `eclipse.ini` file located in Mac?

Comment: Inside Eclipse's insallation folder. Mine:
'eclipse//cpp-oxygen/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini'