# How to resolve error with Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, macos-high-sierra, eclipse-oxygen

I am using Mac OS High Sierra. When I change the workspace in Eclipse it shows following message:

Error message:
[image: error message]

Here is my `.log` file:

[image: .log]

Comment: What is in the log file?

Comment: In case you use Java 9, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46369792/6505250

Comment: Should I print the image of log file?

Comment: /Users/sochetra_nov/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-10-05 at 4.04.05 PM.png

Comment: Links go down so your question should be understandable without any link. Please add a discription of what happens and what the message is

Comment: Please make sure your question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46369792/6505250

Comment: I already follow that but It won't work

Comment: This is definitely because you are using Java 9 and you need to do exactly what the answer in the duplicate tells you to do (or go back to Java 8, or wait for Eclipse Oxygen.1a released on Oct 11).