# Eclipse is not "starting" after download

Tags: eclipse, metadata, logfile

I downloaded eclipse, extracted it, then I selected the workplace, and whenever I press launch it says: "an error occurred. see the log file c:\users\Hesh\eclipse-workplace.metadata.log.".

1. I did the "Environment Variables" thing.
2. My JDK is the newest.
3. I have deleted every Eclipse I had before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't eclipse oxygen start (for the first time)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369792/why-wont-eclipse-oxygen-start-for-the-first-time)

Comment: @howgler - it's not a duplicate and even if it is, the link you provided has no final answer.

Comment: @Seinfeld Java 9 has just been released. You have to wait for Eclipse Oxygen.1a (October 11, 2017), use a [release candidate (BETA version)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?release=oxygen) or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/6505250

Comment: Show us the content of the .log file. But if you are using Java 9 the duplicate applies.

Comment: @greg-449 _"My JDK is the newest."_ = Java 9. The _"not a duplicate"_ comment is is not from the questioner, but from someone who doesn't use Eclipse (according to his deleted answer)