# error in root\workspace\.metadata\.log

Tags: eclipse

I try to run eclipse, but I can not.
The software creates an error in the `root\workspace\.metadata\.log` folder. But I did not understand anything.
Here is the log file:

[Log File](https://www.zeta-uploader.com/en/1200161829)

Also, I did not find a file named ".snap" at the address given. I deleted the workspace folder. I even deleted the software and installed it again. But none of them worked.

Comment: The problem is Eclipse Oxygen.1 (4.7.1) with Java 9. I recommend using [Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/). Alternatively,  edit `eclipse.ini` as follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/6505250

Comment: Wow...Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

In the workspace folder there is a folder with the name ".metadata". and in this folder there is a file with the name ".log".

So the actual path will be:

"/root/workspace/.metadata/.log"

In Linux you might need to use `ls -la` to see the folder ".metadata" and the file ".log".

Check also the file eclipse.ini in the root folder of the Eclipse installation. In this file you could specify the `-vm` parameter and point it to the JVM dll or "so" files directly.

For example:

```
-vm
D:\talend\jre1.8.0_91\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Comment: it's eclipse.ini code: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
...i must to change it????

Comment: Thank. I am still not allowed to give a positive vote.sorry

Comment: Regarding the eclipse.ini file: depends. See first, if you can find the "*.log*" file somewhere in the Eclipse folder. Try some recursive search for the "*.log*" file, like e.g. in Linux `find . -print | grep .log`. If Eclipse cannot find then the Java for some reason you can use the -vm parameter as described above.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much English.
I found the .log file, but I did not understand anything.
Can you simply explain what to do?

Comment: i use windows 7

Comment: Do you see any errors in the .log file? Something saying "error" or "exception"?

Comment: see firest comment from howlger. I'm sorry if I had a bad word. I use Google translation