# “An error has occurred. See the log file .metadata/.log.” CANT FIND METADATA FILE

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm panicking a lot because I just installed JDK 9 and tried to run eclipse and got this error. I looked for the metadata file and can't find it. I'm scared of losing all my work I don't know what to do. I'm using mac os.

This is my ini file, not sure how i can edit it

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: Don't worry, there's no reason not being able to run Eclipse would cause you to lose your work. That work is held in files in the file system, not Eclipse itself. Hopefully someone who knows Eclipse can help with the actual problem. Note that you don't want to look for *"...for the metadata file..."*, you want to look for a file called `.log` inside a directory called `.metadata`. If you're using \*nix, by convention both the directory and the file will be hidden by default in file managers and `ls`; use the "show hidden files" feature of your file manager (or `-a` in `ls`) to see them.

Comment: If you installed Java 9 you need to upgrade to Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a), earlier versions will not run with Java 9 unless you modify the eclipse.ini (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/2670892))

Comment: i can't access eclipse so i can upgrade it. Is there a way i can unisintall Java 9?

Comment: Try de-installing Java9. Or changing your setup so that eclipse finds Java8 in the path. Beyond that: we can't help much with such input. You are like a guy calling his garage "my car is making strange noises. how do i fix that?"

Comment: @greg-449 thanks I uploaded my ini file, should I just place the --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM after the -vmargs?

Comment: Yes, add as a separate line after the -vmargs line

Comment: @greg-449 I did that but now I get this error when I run the program (eclipse opened) 'You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8. The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install.

In case you want to turn off this check open your preferences and go to General > Startup and Shutdown and uncheck 'JavaFX Tooling Java Check''

Comment: I don't know anything about 'JavaFX Tooling'. It sounds like it may not be compatible with Java 9.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your help/