# Eclipse crashes when loading workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

It says an error has occurred and tells me to check the log file.

I'm using Eclipse Neon 4.6.0.

This is my .log file: https://pastebin.com/FqQc1agM

I kind of have a feeling it is this section here, but I have no idea what this means:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2018-01-16 09:28:42.578
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\dwagner'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

I tried searching for people with similar problems but nobody seems to be having issues with crashing when a *workspace* is being loaded, only just initial loading. I tried to take a look at the .log file but can't make anything useful out of it as I'm not super knowledgeable about applications troubleshooting like this.

Comment: At a guess your workspace and/or Eclipse installation is bad.  Try first with a brand new workspace and see what happens (you may need to rename the current workspace directory).  If that doesn't change the issue then I'd remove and reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: The errors at the end of the log are the most up to date. This looks like you are trying to run an old Eclipse with Java 9 - this won't work unless you update the eclipse.ini (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/2670892)). For full Java 9 support you need the current Eclipse (4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to diagnose your problem, without having direct access to the log files and to your system. Best suggestion I can make is to open a **new**, empty workspace (by modifying the `data` parameter in the `eclipse.ini` file). Then, open Eclipse and **import** the older projects into the new workspace.

**Drawback**: In this way, you won't loose your code, but you'll do loose your plugins and several configurations.