# IBM Rational Software Architect (eclipse) - Failing on startup

Tags: java, eclipse, rational-rsa

I have tried to install IBM Rational Software Architect. At the end of the installation it says that it has installed the software but failed to initiate eclipse. When I try to launch the RSA (the software) it fails with this error message: "See the log file
/Users/danielamir/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/.metadata/.log.". So I checked the log file, which contained this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-04-19 11:04:16.858
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
   at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
   ... 21 more
```

I have also already tried this below which didn't work:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9ed43812-9c67-4fd5-921b-f7acb405e12b

Comment: You are trying to run it with Java 9 or 10 but it is too old. You may be able to use the fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/2670892) but I don't know if that works with RSA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your Java_Home is not set in the environment variables.

Comment: Any instructions on how to do this?