# Scala IDE throwing error whens starting up

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide

Scala IDE throwing error when starting up. I have tried to find the solution to this problem but to no avail.

**Solutions I have tried.**

[image]

Trying changing the version of java installation

I have tried all **7,8,9,10 version of Java** alongwith the shutting down of the Mac.

I have also upgraded the SBT version--> no success.

Tried to delete the .metadata directory--> no success

Versions of software that I am using

**sbt -> 1.1.6**

**Scala -> Scala compiler version 2.12.6**

**EDIT: posting the abbreviated contents on the log file**

```
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/utkarshrathor/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-07-18 10:12:52.810
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

.
.
.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

..

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418

..
..

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-18 10:12:52.820
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy

..
..

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418

..
..

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

..
..

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

..
..

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418

..
.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy

..

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
```

Comment: Did you look in the .log file - there will be more details there

Comment: @greg-449 I have edited the answer.

Comment: That error usually means you are trying to run an old Eclipse with Java 9 or 10.  There should be a `java.version=xxx` near the top of the log which tells you which Java was used. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46369792/2670892) for more details

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I was running Java 8 but still your comment pointed me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @greg-449 I looked into **"eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini"** file and added the **"--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"** line below **-vmargs** line. And it started the scala IDE.

Also this answer helped me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/4390618