# Eclipse IDE won't launch

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am not a regular user of this IDE but I need it to follow an online course. Anyways, when I try to open up eclipse it asks me to declare a workspace folder; when I do I get a pop-up error to check the log file which says:

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

Comment: What versions of Eclipse and Java? You are probably using an old version which will not run with newer versions of Java. Be sure to use the current version of Eclipse (2020-03) and at least Java 8.

Comment: What version of Java you have?
However, try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369792/why-wont-eclipse-oxygen-start-for-the-first-time) solution.

Comment: @NichL i am running java neon v3 but i had both jdk 8 and 14 on my system but I was able to work it out by changing the jdk configuration in eclipse.ini from 14 to 8 following the solution linked to. Thank you to both you gentlemen!

Comment: Thank you to both you gentlemen! @greg-449

Comment: I was able to find an answer following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369792/why-wont-eclipse-oxygen-start-for-the-first-time